# Criando uma única função

Tags: php

Como posso fazer o código abaixo ficar em uma única `function`, pois estou tendo uma certa dificuldade.

```
<?php

// Procura por um valor especifico para aplicar valor verdadeiro ou falso
function encontrarValor($urlgeral, $nomeserver){
    if (preg_match("/(\\W|^){$nomeserver}(\\W|$)/i", $urlgeral))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


$host = 'paste2.com = Mega,meohost.com = Meo,google.com = gdriver';

$separacao = explode(',',$host);
foreach ($separacao as $i) {
$filtro = explode(' = ',$i);

// Aplica o valor da url e verifica se a palavra e a mesma caso seja ira por o valhor = para trocar.

if (encontrarValor('google.com', $filtro[0])) { 
    echo "sim ". $filtro[0]." = ".$filtro[1]." \n"; 
}  else { 
    echo "$filtro[1] não e o servidor cadastrado. \n"; 
}


}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você quer verificar se algum item da lista corresponde a `google.com`:

```
$hosts = 'paste2.com = Mega,meohost.com = Meo,google.com = gdriver';
foreach(explode(',', $hosts) as $item) {
    list($url, $nome) = explode(' = ', $item);
    $lista[$url] = $nome;
}

if (array_key_exists($link = 'google.com', $lista)) {
    echo "sim $link=$lista[$link]";
}
```

Comment: Não só da google qualquer servidor no caso na função só foi o valor da google que fiz dar true.